# How do I bypass the recaptcha using Python?

Tags: python, recaptcha

I'm trying to log into a website using Python.

I'm using the Requests Module and Beautiful Soup so far.

I was able to get the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" with following code:

```
 get = s.get(url, headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, "lxml")
 csrf = soup.find("input",{"name":"csrfmiddlewaretoken"})["value"]
 data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf
```

Now I thought I could do the same with the "g-recaptcha-response" with the following code:

```
  recaptcha = soup.find("input",{"id":"recaptcha-token"})["value"]
  data["g-recaptcha-response"] = recaptcha
```

That of course doesn't work.

When I inspect the login page in my browser I can find what I'm looking for.

[Firefox Developer Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBMQz.png)

The value appears once I click the "I am not a robot" Captcha.

Now I need some ideas how to integrate the value into my data dictionary so I can successfully login.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks for help circumventing security measures

Comment: Well... Why do you think they went through the pain of developping this "I'm not a robot" thing if a robot could easily go around it?